# FriendsOfCake CakePdf not working in version 3.8.5

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I am trying to implement cakepdf in my script

In route I have added pdf extension

```
Router::extensions(['pdf']);
```

I also loaded dompdf

In tags controller I have added below code

```
public function initialize()
    {
        parent::initialize();
            Configure::write('CakePdf', [
                'engine' => 'CakePdf.DomPdf',
                'margin' => [
                    'bottom' => 15,
                    'left' => 50,
                    'right' => 30,
                    'top' => 45
                ],
                'orientation' => 'landscape',
                'download' => true
            ]);
    }
```

Also added view builder in view.ctp

```
public function view($id = null)
    {
        $tag = $this->Tags->get($id, [
            'contain' => ['Bookmarks']
        ]);

        $this->viewBuilder()->options([
                'pdfConfig' => [
                    'filename' => 'Invoice_' . $id
                ]
        ]);

        $this->set('tag', $tag);
    }
```

I am getting below output

[image]

Comment: Check your debug/error logs.

Comment: hi @ndm I have checked both debug and error log. No any log found for this error. Debug mode also enable.

Comment: Then check the generated source next (download the file (arrow icon on the top right), or inspect the response (F12 > Network > Select Request > Response Tab, payload is possibly base64 encoded).